# Installed Helvetica font now text on some sites look different

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, css

I just installed Helvetica fonts to do some work in Photoshop. Now when I go to a website with Google Chrome all of the text looks different.

In my example I went to [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) and saw the following:

[image: How I see pro webmasters now]

This is what it should look like:

[image: expected look of pro webmasters]

I assume that this is because I installed Helvetica which is the font set in the CSS on the website while on another such as Super User has Arial.

Is my only solution to uninstall the fonts? Or can I over-ride the fonts being used by a website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you installed Helvetica, things changed in the way you see pages that use e.g. `font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;`, like the Pro Webmasters page does. When Helvetica was not installed, Arial was used instead.

You can use some browser add-on to override page styles in part. In Chrome, Stylebot looks promising. Appears to be easy to use and does not even require knowledge about CSS. The difficult part is to select the elements that need to be styled in order to override the font.

Comment: I'm quite good writing CSS, but I ended up deleting the fonts. I rather not have any other addons if I don't need  them.

Answer (score 0):

I installed TaperMonkey into Google Chrome and then added the "Kill Helvetica" script. This is a band-aid solution but it's fixed for now and I don't have to see ugly, crunched fonts anymore.

Good luck!